# regexp to match java package name

Tags: regex, bash

I want to check if arguments passed in stdin to see if they conform to a valid java package name. The regex I have is not working properly. With the following code passing in com.example.package I receive the error message. I'm not sure what is wrong with my regex?

```
 regex="/^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*(\.[a-z0-9_]+)+[0-9a-z_]$/i"
 17         if ! [[ $1 =~ $regex ]]; then
 18                 >&2 echo "ERROR: invalid package name arg 1: $1"
 19                 exit 2
 20         fi
```

Comment: Do you care for keywords? Invalid package names like "package" or "com.example.class" would be hard to detect with a simple regex, I'd guess. Or do you just need the very basic syntax check (if so you might want to know that upper case characters are actually valid)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are pretty close to the correct solution. Just tweak the regex a bit (also consider @fede's simpler regex) and set the `nocasematch` option for case insensitive matching. For example:

```
regex='^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*(\.[a-z0-9_]+)+[0-9a-z_]$'

shopt -s nocasematch
if ! [[ $1 =~ $regex ]]; then
  exit 2
fi
shopt -u nocasematch
```

You are probably being misled by other languages that use `/regex/i` (javascript) or `qr/regex/i` (perl) for defining a case-insensitive regex object.

Btw, Using `grep -qi` is another, more portable, solution. Cheers.

Comment: Package "a" doesn't match.

Comment: @Marboni I think maybe it's nicer like this: "^[a-z][a-z0-9_]+(\.[a-z0-9_]*)*$", although I prefer it like this (in Java): "(?x) [a-z][a-z0-9_]* ( \\. [a-z][a-z0-9_]* ) *". The (?x) flag makes it a lot easier to read regexes.

Comment: a package is allowed to start with "_", upper case letters are allowed

Answer (score 7):

You could use a simpler regex like this:

```
(?:^\w+|\w+\.\w+)+$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/eE4aY9/1)**

Comment: I see in the demo that it works but when I change my variable to it it still outputs the error. regex="^(?:\w+|\w+\.\w+)+$" gives me ERROR: invalid package name arg 1: com.example.package

Comment: Doesn't your working demo allow "1.invalid.package"?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: try this with `com.package.java.pack.new.`.

Comment: @stribizhev it didn't match, although because of a catastrophic backtracking lol

Comment: @Fede: I hope you know why.

Comment: @stribizhev actually I know too many repetitions within a repeated group is really heavy but haven't debugged that learn how bad it is. But I learn day by day, so if you know feel free to explain it

Comment: Please just fix your pattern.

Answer (score 2):

As per Java package naming *conventions*, the basic syntax

- allows only lower case English alphabets,numbers, _ and .
- must start with alphabet
- can't be malformed eg: contains .. | endsWith . | contains Java keywords

Ignoring the keyword constraint, the regex can be

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*(\.[a-z0-9_]+)*[a-z0-9_]*$

//regex breakdown
//^[a-z]            start with one lowercase English alphabet
//[a-z0-9_]*        followed by zero or more of alphabets, numbers or _
//(\.[a-z0-9_]+)*   zero or more of these
//                          .(one or more of alphabet|number|_)
//[a-z0-9_]*$       must end in alphabet|number|or _
```

[try](https://regex101.com/r/wpryj1/3)

This differs from @gvalkov's answer by

- allowing the number of word.word constructs to be zero
- augmenting last char check with * to correctly detect last char even in presence of word.word matches

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a better approach

```
^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*(?:\.[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)*$
```

Comment: This is the only correct solution, Java package names may contain mixed cases, though they _should_ be all lower case. Alos his pattern does not allow package names like `2pak.is.invalid`